# Консольный ввод зацикливается в Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

При консольном вводе через input() более чем одного значения ввод зацикливается и не прекращается, даже если ввести end. OS - Ubuntu 16.04, shell - Bash.

```
l = []

inp = input()

while inp != "end":
    l.append(int(inp))
    inp = input()

count, ind1 = 0, 0

while ind1 < len(l) - 1:
    if l[ind1] % 10 == 2 or l[ind1 + 1] % 10 == 2:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Ввожу у себя end — ввод прекращается. Уточните, как вы запускаете, какая ОС, в какой консоли

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в бесконечном цикле:

```
while ind1 < len(l) - 1:
   ...
```

Потому что вы не изменяете длину списка `l` (`len(l)`), и, соответственно, `ind1` всегда меньше `len(l)`.

В таком случае, вам просто надо добавить в цикл удаление последнего элемента из списка с помощью `l.pop()`

```
while ind1 < len(l) - 1:
    if l[ind1] % 10 == 2 or l[ind1 + 1] % 10 == 2:
        count += 1
        l.pop()
```

Comment: `pop()` удаляет последний элемент в списке.  Это, конечно, помогает цикл закончить, только что он по вашему считает, если `ind1` всегда ноль (не кажется полезным одну и ту же пару проверять, игнорируя практически все другие значения).

Answer (score 1):

Добавление простого `print("мы здесь", flush=True)` после цикла ввода показало бы, что он прекратился и зацикливание происходит на следующем цикле.

Альтернативно, можно запустить отладчик, например, в вашем Python IDE или просто `python -mpdb ваш-скрипт.py` с командной строки.  Отладчик позволяет детально посмотреть что происходит и является полезным инструментом для ознакомления с поведением кода.

Для простого кода, можно на http://pythontutor.com прямо в браузере поведение кода наглядно посмотреть.

Также полезно читать код и пробовать понять что он делает (модель создавать). Даже беглый осмотр кода должен выявить, что `ind1` индекс нигде не изменяется и длина коллекции не меняется, поэтому если было введено больше одного числа (чтобы условие в while выполнилось), то цикл никогда не закончится.

---

Чтобы устранить ошибку и одновременно уменьшить вероятность новой ошибки, упростите цикл: не используйте явные индексы, если возможно напрямую обходить элементы в коллекции.

1. чтобы вызывать `input()` функцию пока она не вернёт `'end'`, преобразовывая каждую введённую строку в целое число:

   ```
   numbers = list(map(int, iter(input, 'end')))
   ```
2. чтобы обойти все набранные числа попарно, подсчитывая количество пар, удовлетворяющих условию `x % 10 ==  2`:

   ```
   print(sum(x % 10 == 2 or y % 10 == 2 for x, y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:])))
   ```

   `zip(L, L[1:])`  позволяет попарно небольшой список `L` обойти. Иначе можно было бы `pairwise()` рецептом из документации `itertools` модуля воспользоваться и читать лениво не более двух строчек за раз.

   `True == 1` и `False == 0` поэтому `sum()` подсчитывает количество пар удовлетворяющих условию.

Эти две строчки—это полный код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

numbers = list(map(int, iter(input, 'end')))
print(sum(x % 10 == 2 or y % 10 == 2 for x, y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:])))
```

Если не ясно, что какая-то функция делает, то вызовите `help()`, к примеру `help(zip)` и/или прочтите [её документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Если из описания не ясно, что функция делает, то попробуйте с ней поиграться в интерактивной Питон консоле:

```
$ ptpython
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(*L)
1 2 3 4 5
>>> print(*zip(L, L[1:]))
(1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, 5)
```

Если застряли где-то, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

бесконечный цикл в if l[ind1] % 10 == 2 or l[ind1 + 1] % 10 == 2: